# Android trying to nest a list in a list via fragments throwing IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Okay, so at a basic level, I'm trying to simply make a series of lists with a series of lists.  The master/flow starting template does this great, except I want to have one more "tier" of lists before I reach my final content.  So, if you know a better way of doing this, feel free to suggest it.

With that being said, this is my implementation.  I took the master/flow template to start, and tried changing the fragment_detail xml (called fragment_game_detail.xml in my case) from a TextView to a RelativeLayout, and this change is seemingly throwing the IAE.

For reference, here is the call stack as I understand it.

```
public void onItemSelected(String id) {

    if (mTwoPane) {

        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(RiskDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        RiskDetailFragment fragment = new RiskDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                   .replace(R.id.game_detail_container,
                                            fragment)
                                   .commit();

    } else {

        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, RiskDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(RiskDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);

    }

}
```

Which calls

```
public void onItemSelected(String id) {

    if (mTwoPane) {

        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(RiskDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        RiskDetailFragment fragment = new RiskDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                   .replace(R.id.game_detail_container,
                                            fragment)
                                   .commit();

    } else {

        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, RiskDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(RiskDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);

    }

}
```

Fragment_game_detail was changed to

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/game_detail"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RiskDetailFragment" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why does clicking that respective item throw an IAE for id/game_detail_container?  I've gone through over a dozen other issues of this being thrown on stack overflow, and none of them are relevant to me that I have found.

Here is the activity_game_detail.xml that contains that id, but I haven't changed it because pointing it to the proper class.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_detail_container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RiskDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

In ListFragment, this may also be part of the issue:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView,
                            View view,
                            int position,
                            long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            RiskDetailFragment fragment = new RiskDetailFragment();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                     .replace(R.id.game_detail_container,
                                              fragment)
                                     .commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                               .replace(R.id.game_detail_container,
```

R.id.game_detail_container needs to be a View ID in your hierarchy. If this is just the name of an item in yor listview it won't work.

What views are in your layout and check their ID's

Comment: That's the thing that baffles me the most.  I didn't change that file at all.

I'll add it to main post for reference.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is because of how I called the other fragment, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Basically, I need to figure out how to have a stack of 3 UI components, and I'm having a hell of a time doing it.